# Flatten a frequency table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
| Number |  Frequency  |
+--------+-------------|
|  0     |  7          |
|  1     |  1          |
|  2     |  3          |
|  3     |  1          |
```

However, I want it to be transformed into one column with all redundant values such as:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3
```

How do I achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the max value in your Frequency column? You wants the output in a single row/column or per value 1 row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this task:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Number, Frequency
  FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number, Frequency - 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Frequency > 1
)
SELECT Number
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Number
```

Output:

```
Number
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
2
2
2
3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc4ce/3)

If you want just a single aggregate value, you can use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the output of the CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Number, Frequency
  FROM data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number, Frequency - 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Frequency > 1
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Number, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Number)
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc4ce/6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive solution (should work in SQL 2005+):

```
select stuff((
    select replicate(concat(', ', n), f)
    from (
        values 
            (0, 7),
            (1, 1),
            (2, 3),
            (3, 1)

    ) as x(n, f)
    for xml path('')
), 1, 2, '');
```

Or, if you're on SQL 2017+, you can go with the less obtuse version (gets rid of the `for xml path` and `stuff()` hack in favor of `string_agg`):

```
select string_agg(replicate(concat(', ', n), f), ',')
from (
    values 
        (0, 7),
        (1, 1),
        (2, 3),
        (3, 1)

) as x(n, f)
```